# Check box checked Automatically in listview when scrolling the list.

Tags: android

I have one problem, i have customize `listview` with `checkbox`.

When i scroll the items the some `checkbox` is automatically `checked` without clicking on `checkbox`.

Can any one help me?

Comment: More specifically, the code for your adapter.getView ...

Answer (score 0):

It means that ou select one checkbox and android will select randomly for that you should use...

```
if(tempVector.get(position)){
            holder.box.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            holder.box.setChecked(false);
        }
```

Try this, it works for me.

Comment: in my scenario...for(int i=0; i < ImageDisplay.newimagelist; i++){

     tempVector.set(i, true);
   } and after this onchacked change i will set the value of true and other are false. but after that also problem is still there so at end of chackedchangedlisner i put this....

Comment: yes dude. if another user will face this issue and he will see this question then he could got right answer..i hope you can understand..

Comment: @CapDroid but it is understood that some vector are there in that we put our checkbox at the size of list.

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        final Season season = (Season) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.season, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.season_title);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.season_check_box);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(season.getTitle());
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                season.setChecked(isChecked);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.checkBox.setChecked(season.isChecked()); // position is important! Must be before return statement!
        return convertView;
    }

    protected class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView title;
        protected CheckBox checkBox;
    }
```

Comment: Anybody who needs an explanation of this code should watch  [Android Google IO 2009 UI performance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA)