# How to manage list views Checkboxes Automatically checking?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview, scrollview

This is my list i want My problem is when i scroll list view then the check boxes(which are the items of this List ) are automatically checked 
ex -  if i checked first then 4 automatically being checked.

My first goal:

```
 1. want to stretch my list to full i will wrap it into Scrollview  how
 2. i can prevent it to automatically checked
```

.

```
<ListView   
android:id="@+id/ListViewProducts"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_column="0"
android:layout_span="2"
android:clickable="true"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:saveEnabled="true"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:scrollbarSize="10sp"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own BaseAdapter.

Keep in mind, that ALL views in your listview you see are temporary. They will be recycled when you'll scroll away. The reason is - you can have >9000 elements in your list. So, the way you create views must depend on some kind of (!) data.

[Here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/) is nince tutorial on how to create your own list.

Make X-th checkbox depend on X-th boolean in the list. A bit confusing first time I know, but this is the best way.

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    List<boolean> myCheckBoxes;

    boolean getItem(int arg0){

        return myCheckBoxes.get(arg0);

    }

    View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2){

        ...
        ...//See article
        myView.setChecked(getItem(arg0));

        ...
        return myView;

    }
```

And in your activity

```
ListView myListView;
...
myListView.setAdapter(new MyAdapger(...));
```

Comment: yes but my problem starts from here Now i want to get the status of check boxes i'm using  ListView.getAdapter().getView(int Position,null,null);

to find the view but its not giving me the right view and its state

Comment: @Photon they wont give you the right view because the listview's views are temporary. to save information about a listview item you need to assign a listener and save its data to another data source (eg an array)

Comment: Make your views "equal" to some data collection. And get info from that. E.g. isSelected(int position){return myCheckboxes.get(position);}

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't put a listview into a scrollview, two views scrolling in the same direction will not work nicely. Just put the listview in your non scrolling layout (frame- , list-, relativelayout).
2. Use an Adapter that sets every listview's row's views according to the data to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

1. ListView already extends ScrollView and doesn't need to have another one to surround it.
2. try looking at this [post on creating custom listView items](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/). you can implement a checkBox in them and make is have `android:checked="false"`

Answer (score 1):

ListVew already extends ScrollView no need to implement it on ListView

for AutoCheck follow this link:

[Check box checked Automatically in listview when scrolling the list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871120/check-box-checked-automatically-in-listview-when-scrolling-the-list)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to implement scrollview in listview becoz it is already extends to scrollview.
I think your listview is not able to handle the recycling of items properly.So to solve this problem go through the below link.

[Getting an issue while checking the dynamically generated checkbox through list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list)